# Is there a way to iterate over a list of dataframes when creating a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, boxplot

I have made this function in R, in order to create boxplots based on the same column in multiple data frames, stored in a list (dfs):

```
plotting <- function(dfs, name="pdf_name", column, names, colours, title="No_title"){
  pdf(name)
  boxplot(dfs[[1]][[column]], dfs[[2]][[column]], dfs[[3]][[column]], names=names, col=colours)
  title(title)
  boxplot(dfs[[1]][[column]], dfs[[2]][[column]], dfs[[3]][[column]], col=colours, names=names, outline=F) #without outliers
  title(paste(title, "without outliers"))
  dev.off()
}
```

I would like to shorten this code, and wonder if there is a way to go through all dataframes in my list of dataframes, like: dfs[[1:3]]?

Comment: Yes.  `row_bind` your data frames together, creating an index variable to indicate the source data frame.  The modify your function to use the combine data frame, using the index variable to define the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me an example of how I modify my function to use the combined data frame?

Comment: Not easily, because your problem is not reproducible.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: `do.call` enables to pass several arguments as a list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use something like this : `do.call(boxplot, append(lapply(dfs, \(df) df$cyl), list(col= "red")))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the `diamonds` data frame and focusing only on the elements of your code that are relevant to your question.

First, create some test data.

```
# Create some test data
dfList <- diamonds %>% group_by(color) %>% group_split()
```

Combine the list of data frames into a single, long data frame

```
testData <- dfList %>% bind_rows(.id="Source")
```

Rewrite the function

```
plotting <- function(d, colName, groupName, title="Default title") {
  boxplot(as.formula(paste0(colName, " ~ ", groupName)), data=d)
  title(title)
  boxplot(as.formula(paste0(colName, " ~ ", groupName)), data=d, outline=FALSE)
  title(paste0(title, ": no outliers"))
}
```

Use the function

```
plotting(testData, "depth", "Source")
```

Which gives two plots that I believe are of the required form.

[The `diamonds` data frame is part of the `ggplot2` package.]